# How can I check if emails can be sent from my phone?

Tags: android, email

I have an app that will send an email from the server if the app user does not have their email set up on their phone. Otherwise it will be sent through the android device.

What methods are there to check if email is configured on the phone?

Thanks

Comment: Ask the user? I think that is a very simple solution.

Comment: Just a small comment, unless you are worried about flooding the server, you should always try to send the email from there. At least I personally would be worried about downvotes in the market due to complaints such are "Ur app makes my phone data Skyrocket!!!1!1" Sure, it isn't that much data and they accepted the terms, but would the emails really break your server? :)

Comment: I think the intent is to minimize the amount of emails that go to the spam folder. Since we're sending the email from a friend, it usually won't go straight there. I was just wondering if there was a method to check if there was an email or not because when I tested it out on a phone with no email it gave me a message saying no email application found and didn't send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to let the user to decide to send the email is to just create and use an Email Intent. That way the user sees that you want to send an email, and can choose what email client sends the email.

Example:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:to@gmail.com"));
```